# AWS Lamdbas use CloudFront distribution domain as environment variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am creating a new stack using various AWS components as well as a few custom functions. My stack defines a `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` distribution to be created when the `sam` deploy command runs. I would like to get the distribution's domain name and use it as an environment variable for two of my functions. Reading the documentation here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudfront-distribution.html

states that one should be able to use the domain name of the distribution by doing this:

`!GetAtt <logical_id>.DomainName`

Thus is went ahead and did this in one of my functions:

```
 RenameAsset:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: 'rename-asset/build/distributions/rename-asset-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip'
      Handler: 'fts.assetiq.renamer.AssetRenamer::handleRequest'
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PUBLIC_CDN_NAME: !GetAtt AssetIQDistribution.DomainName
      Events:
        RenameAssetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref AssetIQApi
            Path: '/assetiq/assets'
            Method: put
```

Problem is that I am still unable to retrieve the domain name use it as an env var. I have tried several other alternative (like using `!Sub` instead of `!GetAtt`) but nothing seems to work. Can anyone shed some light on this. For reference my distribution configuration is the following:

```
  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: 'Asset-IQ Origin Identity'

  AssetIQDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !GetAtt S3Bucket.DomainName
            Id: !Sub S3-assetiq-${ApplicationStage}
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity:
                Fn::Sub: 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
        Enabled: 'true'
        Comment: "asset iq cloudfront distribution"
        Logging:
          IncludeCookies: 'false'
          Bucket: assetiq-logs.s3.amazonaws.com
          Prefix: assetiq-logs_
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          Compress: 'true'
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          TargetOriginId: !Sub S3-assetiq-${ApplicationStage}
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'false'
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        PriceClass: PriceClass_100
        ViewerCertificate:
          CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: 'true'
        IPV6Enabled: false
```

Comment: Are these are two different CF stacks? You can't refer to a resource from one stack in the other using a logical resource reference. You can use cross-stack references - output the distribution name from the first stack (in `Outputs`) and import it into the second (`!ImportValue`).

Comment: You can get the domainName like this `- DomainName: !Select [2, !Split ["/", !GetAtt S3Bucket.WebsiteURL]]`. A URL is returned by S3 bucket when a call is made with `!GetAtt S3Bucket.WebsiteURL]` so the https:// prefix needs to be removed by splitting the URL. You can output the CloudFront domain name with `Value: !GetAtt [AssetIQDistribution, DomainName]`.

Comment: @jarmod what do you mean by different CF stacks?

Comment: Is this all in one CloudFormation stack, or are the CloudFront resources created in one stack and then the remaining resources created in a 2nd stack.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question as it the issue has been resolved. Turns out the SAM template configuration was correct but I was referring the system environment variable with a wrong key, resulting in a null returned value.

Correcting that on code level resolved the problem and it seems that referencing the domain name the way I did originally works pretty much fine.